# Use unison between two Windows PCs

Tags: sync, unison

I have used unison to sync files between Linux and Windows XP.
Now I need to sync files between two Windows XP machines. Has anyone done it before?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is fairly simple. Assuming that you setup a network share, you can just do:

```
unison.exe e:\photos \\other\photos
```

I typically just automate it with

```
unison.exe e:\photos \\other\photos -auto
```

Whatever command line switches you use between Windows and Linux will work here.

The UI also works just as well.